# How to get file name from input file with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get name from current uploaded file, I'm sure I'm pretty close, but can't reach exact name.
When I'm using this:

```
$('.technicalDraw').on('change', '#file-upload', function () {
  console.log($(this.files))
})
```

I get this output:
[image]

but when I'm trying something like this:

```
$('.technicalDraw').on('change', '#file-upload', function () {
  console.log($(this.files.name))
})
```

I recive this:

[image]

How can I reach filename.pdf?

Cheers

Comment: try with `this.files[0].name`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen doesn't work - shows me this: jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)], and it's without any connection with my uploaded file

Comment: Just `this.files[0]` not `$(this.files[0])` - if you're getting `jquery.fn.init` then you've used `$()` somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this if there is only 1 file:

`$(this)[0].files[0].name`

or

`this.files[0].name`

If there is multiple files I would look thought each file to display the name.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#file-upload', function () {
  console.log(this.files[0].name)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" />
```